# Mysql identical queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SELECT query where you search by car owners.
Every owner can have more than one car.
There is **random** generated list of cars of which we have to find owners.

```
...

$owners[] = $dbaseowners["ownerid"] // owner ID's fetched from database

$owners = implode (',',$owners);

SELECT carname FROM cars WHERE ownerid IN ($owners);
```

My problem is when one owner is used more than once for example: IN (1,1,4,1) - mysql only fetch one 'copy' of this owner's data.

Since i have a randomly generated car list, I have to have owner row for every car no matter if owner is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are fetching any owner information with your query.  It seems to me that your query would return all carnames with owners in your list.  So if a single owner had 10 cars, all 10 would be in your result set.

Comment: Your statement says "There is a random generated list of cars".  However, your code has "ownerid in ($owners)".  Which is it?  A randomly selected list of cars or owners?

Comment: List of cars is already fetched from database. Every car has ownerID which are all collected in $owners variable and after that there is select query where i search for owners based on which cars are on the list. The problem is mysql doesnt duplicate queries with same numbers inside IN() statement. But i need that since i dont know which cars are on the list and since one owner can own more than one car

Comment: If you are fetching a list of cars and use that to retrieve the owner details, you should update the query that retrieves the cars to also retrieve the owner details. Use `JOIN` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to revise your design and have a join table to relate the owners to cars. Having 1,1,4,1 in one row of table is not compliant with the first normal form and you should avoid using it.

Comment: You don't need a join table(unless cars are also owned by multiple owners). You do, however, need a join query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_unique` to remove duplicate values from your array:

```
...

$owners[] = $dbaseowners["ownerid"] // owner ID's fetched from database

$owners = implode (',', array_unique($owners));

SELECT carname FROM cars WHERE ownerid IN ($owners);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `ownerid`, `carname` FROM `cars` WHERE `ownerid` IN (".array_unique($owners).")");
$ret = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $ret[$row['ownerid']] = $row['carname'];
foreach($owners as $owner) {
    echo $owner.": ".$ret[$owner]."<br />\n";
}
```